# Building a select option dropdown: Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, jsx

I have the following snippet of React JSX code that renders a select option dropdown from a list of values.

```
renderRoleDropdown(user_role) {
let values = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

return (
  <select onChange={() => /* some logic here */ }>
    {
      values.map((value, _i) => {
        let label = getDisplayLabelForValue(value);
        return <option key={value} value={value}>{label}</option>;
      })
    }
  </select>
 );
}
```

As far as I can tell this conforms to how other examples works - just looping through a list and building an array of `<option>` elements. However when I run it I get

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys
>   {options}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an
>   array instead.

I'm not using an object and I'm clearly returning an Array, so wondering why it doesn't like that?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give all the component code, or create a minimal sandbox?

Answer (score 0):

You had a lot syntax error (pascal names, no chars) - now it's works.
You can also use value instead label.

I can't reflect the rest of the code - I don't know its purpose.

---

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, Component } from 'react'

let RenderRoleDropdown = () => {

    let values = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

    return (
        <select>
            {
                values.map((value, _i) => {
                    let label = "random value"
                    return <option key={value} value={value}>{label}</option>;
                })
            }
        </select>
    );
}

export default RenderRoleDropdown;
```

[image]

[image]